# How to use WSL Ubuntu for my rails project that i have started using windows rails after installing ubuntu sub-system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have been working on a rails project in windows so I was recommended to use Linux to solve my issue. I have installed the WSL ubuntu subsystem but I don't know how I can go forward with my previous project in ubuntu?
Do I install rails again?
And how do I do that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  As a heads-up - This question, IMHO, doesn't really meet the criteria of being a "programming question".  Really, you are asking how to *use* Linux and WSL.  The short answer is "yes", you need to install Rails into WSL Ubuntu and copy your project over to the WSL.  As for "how", I'd ask you to do some [Search and Research](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first.  Search for *install Rails on Ubuntu* and *copy files from Windows to WSL*.  Then come back and (likely on [Super User](https://superuser.com)), ask again if something you find doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not really sure I completely understand the question but you can just install Rails like with a normal Ubuntu distro. [Here's the guide](https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/21.04). And just select which Ubuntu version you are using.